# is converting Lua to spir-v possible?

Tags: c++, lua, compilation, vulkan

I want to write shader code in Lua but it needs to be covered to spir-v. I have not come across a non-glsl compiler for it yet. Is this possible to do?

Comment: *anything is possible with an additional layer of abstraction*

Comment: Create a graph of each LUA keyword, command and type of code block connected to a flow chart or some diagram of the commands in SPIR-V to accomplish the same result, manage context, etc. Step two, write a dispatcher which can issue any line of SPIR-V dynamically given arguments. Step 3, detect situations where you can simplify the SPIR-V by batching or reduction. Now you have a basic Lua-to-SPIR-V interpreter. Documenting the different algorithms involved would be the tedious part, but coding each would be individually trivial.

Answer (score 4):

It certainly is possible (to make a converter from [Lua](http://lua.org/) to SPIR-V), but it is a lot of work (certainly several years, if you want the generated [SPIR-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Portable_Intermediate_Representation) code to be efficient). You'll need to write a Lua to SPIR-V compiler.

If you want to go on that route, read several books about compilation, starting with the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). Of course, [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (in your Lua -> SPIR-V compiler) is really important

You have tagged your question as `C++`. If you want something related to C++ about SPIR-V consider using [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC)

My recommendation is to **stay reasonable:** if you want to code for a [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units), use a dedicated low-level  [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) language like [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (or [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)). You are likely to need to write only short routines ([compute kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compute_kernel)) in that (OpenCL or CUDA) language (and more glue code, e.g. to be able to use them from a Lua program, or even a C++ or a C one).

Answer (score 2):

Lua, as a high-level scripting language, has a number of features that SPIR-V, as a low-level shading language, either 1) cannot handle at all, 2) can only handle inefficiently, or 3) cannot handle transparently (ie: the code invoking the shader operation needs to do different stuff).

For example, Lua makes functions first-class objects with lexical scoping. That might be possible in SPIR-V, but it would require memory allocation. And SPIR-V can't do that; it can only work with the memory objects that the external system provides. So this means that the code invoking the shader operation needs to provide storage of some sort to the shader process. How much would depend on what the script does.

Also, SPIR-V has no concept of strings, yet pretty much everything in Lua relies on that. So you'll have to manufacture strings out of whole cloth. And since it cannot allocate memory, the external system would again be required to provide storage for strings.

Lua tables would also be incredibly expensive to implement. Not only do they require dynamic allocation, they also require lots of memory access indirection. Accessing a table with a runtime string value would hurt shader performance. And since Vulkan-flavored SPIR-V require logical addressing, implementing tables will require not having actual pointers. So you'll have to use some sort of array with an index.

Oh, and Lua has none of the data structures or syntax that SPIR-V and shaders work with. SPIR-V needs to communicate with the outside world through a very well defined interface, consisting of typed and decorated variable declarations. Lua has no way of explicitly defining the type of variables, let along decorating them, so you'll have to invent such grammar.

Lua (pre-5.3) also lacks a formal notion of the distinction between a float and an integer. This decision is *very important* for SPIR-V, as it helps define the interface between a shader stage and the outside world.

Oh, and SPIR-V outright forbids recursion. So even if you managed to make all of the above work, there's no way to *guarantee* that all Lua shaders could work as a SPIR-V shader.

Is it possible? Probably. Is it at all *reasonable*? No.